# getting weird error "')' expected.ts(1005)" in App.js

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to React and below is the code which is throwing the error.

I've created project with create-react-app and Text is function component already defined

I did google but couldn't find solution

```
//import logo from './logo.svg';
//import './App.css';
import React from 'react';
import Text from './components/Text';

function App() {
  return (
      <Text />
    {/* <div className="App">  **at this line it throws error "')' expected.ts(1005)"**
        <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <p>
          Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
        <a
          className="App-link"
          href="https://reactjs.org"
          target="_blank"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
        >
          Learn React
        </a>
      </header>
    </div> */}
  );
}

export default App;
```

[image]

Comment: just remove the comment

Comment: But it's valid JSX right, I've put multi line comment inside { }

Comment: Is this VS Code bug ? When { } are outside parent node it's throwing error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the whole code including commented inside a parent `<div></div>` or a higher order tag `<></>` your error will disappear.

Answer (score -1):

[Check image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/njQX3.png)

Please check below code it's running fine.

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import Text from './Text'
function App() {
return (
<div className="App">
<Text/>
</div>
);
}
export default App;
```